# Facebook error subcode 1870034

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have a automated job to publish some data to facebook through API, it was working fine until recently it started throwing error 
**com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Permissions error (code 200, subcode 1870034)**

I googled subcode 1870034 but no help, if anyone have encountered this error previously ,please explain regarding this subcode.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Dunno. Suggest you go check the changelog first of all, to see what might have happened regarding the specific functionality you are using there.

Comment: There are no recent changes, and as i mentioned it is an automated job which is successfully running for quite a long time. just wanted to know the description for subcode 1870034

Comment: Can’t find anything on that, at least not in combination with error code 200. You can either file a bug report and ask them what the meaning of that specific sub-code is, or do a little debugging to try and figure out what might be missing yourself.

Comment: Im having the same issue. creating custom audiences was working fine untill recently. Nothing has changed from my side. One day it stopped working and gave me permission error. I have already agreed to TOS. @anks have you solved it or know any more details?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem it's related to TOS. For me error looked like

`{"error":{"message":"Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"error_subcode":1870047,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Audience Size too Low","error_user_msg":"You cannot remove users from this audience because it will result in a low audience size.","fbtrace_id":"xxx"}}`

Here you can find an official answer from FB team
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2093728693993530

> Thanks for writing in. I can confirm that this is a valid error message. Custom Audiences must maintain a certain minimum size, though the specific number is not actually documented. I believe the required minimum is approximately 100 unique users. If you need to remove so many users that you're going under this limit, I'd recommend deleting the custom audience entirely.

Also why it's `Permissions error`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue for error subcode `1870034`, which seems to come from a Custom Audience TOS issue, here is the full error message

> You'll need to agree to the Custom Audience terms before you can
>   create or edit an audience of CUSTOM type.

You can try accept the Custom Audience TOS using this link `https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos/?act=AD_ACCOUNT_ID`
(Though you'd probably need to own the ad account in this case)

Comment: hey twenizaak, thanks for your answer, is this resolved for you guys?, because we have accepted the TOS but still it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Which endpoint are you using? I know there is a few different TOS's since GDPR.
Value-based lookalike audiences https://www.facebook.com/customaudiences/value_based/tos
The rest of them via this link
https://adespresso.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213984478-Missing-some-ToS-for-Custom-Audiences-

Comment: @anks have you solved the problem? I've accepted the TOS and still getting the same error.

Comment: yes it is working for me know , to make it work, if you are the admin accept all the TOS , if not then anyone 1 admin to accept.

Comment: refer these as well https://adespresso.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213984478-Missing-some-ToS-for-Custom-Audiences- and

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1697739793635397/?disable_redirect=0